# Saving data from replicated simulations in R

Tags: r, function, dataset, replicate

I created a small function that generates a table of Data. Then, I want **R** to replicate this function many times, so I included my function inside a "replicate()" function.
This seems to work great.

Now, I want to save the results of every simulation in one table. I've tried rbind, data.table etc... but clearly I am doing it wrong.

```
replicate(100,{object<-function{....
results<-(table of results)
}})
```

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example? I am struggling to understand what you really want to do.

Comment: try `replicate(...,simplify = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand corectly but the easiest thing for me is use some condinional function. For example:

```
i<-1
main.table<-data.frame()

while (i<=100) {
object<-function (...)
main.table<-rbind(main.table,object) 
i<-i+1
}
```